# How to increase performance in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization

Hi im new to swift and my game is a random generated square that fall down at a random speed, im having trouble with my function (this function is executed when the user touch a square):

```
let Font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Medium", size: 16)
let bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Destroy-Square", withExtension: "mp3")!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    do {
        try  SquareDestroyedSound =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, fileTypeHint: nil) }
    catch _{
        return print("no sound file")
    }
SquareDestroyedSound.prepareToPlay()
}

     func SquareExploded (pos: CGPoint, nodeColor: String, Points: String) {
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: Font?.fontName)
        let emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ExplodedWhiteSquare.sks")
        myLabel.fontSize = 20
        myLabel.text = Points
        myLabel.position = pos
        actionMovePoint = SKAction.moveToY(pos.y + 200, duration: 0.8)
        self.addChild(myLabel)
        myLabel.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMovePoint, actionMoveDonePoint]))
        emitterNode!.particleColorSequence = nil
        emitterNode!.particleColorBlendFactor = 1.0
        emitterNode!.particleColor = UIColor(rgba: nodeColor)
        emitterNode!.particlePosition = pos
        self.addChild(emitterNode!)
        emitterNode!.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2), completion: { emitterNode!.removeFromParent() })
        SquareDestroyedSound.play()
    }
```

This function need to do three things at the same time :

1- myLabel is a text that go up from the touched square position for 0.8 second and then it should be removed.

2- emitterNode which is a spark effect that i create it, this effect get the square position and the color to produce an effect that have the same color as the touched square, the duration for this effect is 2 seconds and then its removed.

3- bgMusicURL/SquareDestroyedSound is url path for the sound for each square is touched and it's played when time

My problem is when the user touche any square the game lag a little bit like the screen freeze and the fps drop from 60 to 55/52. The function work fine if i don't use this function the game don't lag any more with no fps drop so i need help is there any way to optimize my code ?

Comment: Try caching the AVAudioPlayer ...

Comment: Sorry but my problem come from each one myLabel , emitterNode and the sound

Comment: How do you catch the AVAudioPlayer in swift ?

Comment: I said caching ... not catching.  Basically, you declare and initialize it in an outer scope (e.g. as some field of your MVC view object) ... and then reuse it.  (I'm not an Swift programmer.  This is general UI implementation stuff.)

Comment: Sorry i will try caching myLabel first

Comment: instead of running the action on `self`, create an SKAction sequence that has the wait and a remove and run it on `emitterNode` directly

Comment: I updated my code i tried to cache myLabel and it work no more lagging even with the emitterNode but when i play sound it lag how to cache sound in Swift ?

Comment: @Paulw1 .... maybe you could write him an answer that shows him what you mean.

Comment: @StephenC - I am a bit reluctant as it is just a guess... Delays in Spritekit are also notoriously called by incorrect font names.

Comment: @Michel I suggest you use the time profiler instrument to determine what the real cause of the delay is - it could be the font name.

Comment: @Paulw11 i tried time profile but i can't find anything linked to font name and its really hard to find something important because CPU usage is really low, i tried to remove sound it doesn't lag anymore so i think i will search a way to cache my sound like i did for font

Comment: good idea - You should always pre-create as many objects as possible when using SpriteKit

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't find how to cache sound in swift -_-

Comment: Just create a property to hold your sound in your initialiser

Comment: @Paulw11 i updated my code so you can see how i call the sound in my didMoveToView method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an `SKAction` sequence to perform all of your operations and avoid the use of `AVAudioPlayer` -

```
func SquareExploded (pos: CGPoint, nodeColor: String, Points: String) {
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: Font?.fontName)
    let emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ExplodedWhiteSquare.sks")
    myLabel.fontSize = 20
    myLabel.text = Points
    myLabel.position = pos
    actionMovePoint = SKAction.moveToY(pos.y + 200, duration: 0.8)
    self.addChild(myLabel)
    myLabel.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMovePoint, actionMoveDonePoint]))
    emitterNode!.particleColorSequence = nil
    emitterNode!.particleColorBlendFactor = 1.0
    emitterNode!.particleColor = UIColor(rgba: nodeColor)
    emitterNode!.particlePosition = pos
    self.addChild(emitterNode!)
    let actionSequence=SKAction.sequence([SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Destroy-Square.mp3", waitForCompletion: false), SKAction.waitForDuration(2),SKAction.removeFromParent()])
    emitterNode!.runAction(actionSequence)
}
```

Comment: Thank you now it doesn't lag anymore :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the following checks:

1. You said it generates a random square falling at random speed? How much randomness? If you input a pre-defined square and speed, does the function
   still create lag?
2. Can any of these be declared statically? If they need to be unique instances, can you predefine a few to save initialisation time?

   let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: Font?.fontName)
   let emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "ExplodedWhiteSquare.sks")
   let bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Destroy-Square", withExtension: "mp3")!

Something like:

```
let emitterNode = emmitterArray.getNextInactiveEmmitter()
let bgMusicURL:NSURL = musicArray.getNextInactiveTrack()
```

Comment: 1. yes it still lag because the sound take too much time i try to caching sound but it didn't work 2. they are unique instance but the problem is coming from the sound only if remove it the game don't lag anymore